# How to inject mock datasource when using in Junit test

Tags: spring, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

In my application,we bind the datasource through the JNDIlook up using below code:

```
<bean id="jndiDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName">
        <value>java:/jboss/datasources/efmDS</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Dao has code like below:

```
   @Autowired
    @Qualifier("jndiDataSource")
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }
```

Now I am having problem while running Junit test case.
I am testing a service method which is annotated with @Transactional.
This service method internally calls some dao method which I have already mocked using mockito but I am facing issues as when transaction is getting started it tries to fetch connection from datasource which is not present and throws communicationslinkfailure exception
How can I mock datasource in this case ? or any other alternative to solve the issue is also appreciated ?

Comment: what is what you really want to do here? use an actual database, but not the production one, and verify that it stores everything correctly? or mock it, so when you call it, you use mockito to mock the output manually when you call the dao to operate with the database?

Comment: If you really want to mock, it sounds like unit test and for such a unit test, I would discourage using Spring. Instead just create the DAO (for example) manually and insert a mocked datasource via the existing setter. This way you remove the whole spring overhead

Comment: @SalvadorJuanMartinez I want to mock.I am using mockito to mock the output

Comment: @Rips then what @Florian Schaetz said in the previous comment is the way to go, get rid of any application context that you are loading and run the test class with `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` instead, and you'll be able to mock the data source.